# MPI_Comm_dup() not working when sending MPI_COMM_NULL as argument

Tags: mpi, mpich

Somewhere I used

```
MPI_Comm_dup(row_comm, &bigger_row_comm);
```

and I noticed it caused 'fatal' error when `row_comm` was equal to `MPI_COMM_NULL`. I changed it with

```
if (row_comm != MPI_COMM_NULL)
    MPI_Comm_dup(row_comm, &bigger_row_comm);
else
    bigger_row_comm = MPI_COMM_NULL;
```

Now it works. I use MPICH and found this in its documentation in [the entry](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Comm_dup.html) for `MPI_Comm_dup`:

> A common error is to use a null communicator in a call (not even allowed in `MPI_Comm_rank`).

I wonder if this behavior is standard and I should expect other implementations to do the same. Why haven't they just handled it like I did? One expects the duplicate of MPI_COMM_NULL to be a MPI_COMM_NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MPI standard](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf) does not specify what `MPI_Comm_dup` shall do when called with an null communicator (see section 6.4.2). Therefore, one cannot assume that such a call is allowed, especially since `MPI_COMM_NULL` is defined as "the value used for invalid communicator handles".

For what it's worth, OpenMPI 4.0.1 also treats the call as an error.